# Что лучше выбрать для интернет-магазина: Opencart или Wordpress + Woocommerce 2019?

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, opencart

Сам веб разработчик с опытом, работал и с первым, и со вторым. Но все таки интересует еще мнения, что бы выбрать. Сам магазин на 300-400 товаров.

Вопросы:

1. с какими проблемами сталкивались при разработке
2. что лучше по SEO, все таки в Opencart с этим проблемно.
3. может какие-то свои нюансы.

Comment: только хардкод =)

Comment: у opencart на мой взгляд намного проще код, он хотя бы соответствует паттерну MVC. Значит все интуитивно понятно.

Comment: В том то и дело что не нужно хардкод, так что бы за часов 30-40 все отладить и в работу

Answer (score 1):

И **Opencart** и **Woocommerce** одинаково хорошо справляются с цепочкой задач *`найти-выбрать-купить-оповестить`*.

С точки зрения администратора магазина, не владеющего навыком работы на `php`, оба магазина позволяют кастомизацию через модули и расширения (плагины), но **Woocommerce** можно расширять(устанавливать дополнения) прямо из админки. Это удобно: ищите фичу, смотрите отзывы, покупаете(скачиваете бесплатно), устанавливаете, пользуете. С **Opencart** делать это придётся руками, не особо сложно, но либо тратить время либо деньги на разработчика.

**Opencart** заточен исключительно под **e-commerce**, это цельная **cms**, тогда как **Woocommerce** это, по сути, плагин для **WP**.

В плане безопасности я предпочитаю **Opencart**, исключительно по причине "дырявой" логики использования плагинов в **WP**. Огромное количество бесплатных плагинов искушают хозяина магазина и неопытного разраба решать их помощью все вопросы. Но многие плагины **WP** дырявые или же заведомо несущие вредоносный код.

В общем, за 30-40 часов на любом из них можно собрать базовую продавалку с минимальным необходимым функциональным набором. Инфы на русском в интернете однозначно больше по **WC**.